# Using the login Details via Application

Tags: php, sql, curl, authentication

I have a CURL(in C++) to send my user and pass to remauth.php file so i think i do something wrong on remuth.php ( because i am basic in php and my program can not run because the auth not passed.) 
I use login via Application.

my CURL:

```
bool Auth_PerformSessionLogin(const char* username, const char* password)
{
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

if (curl)
{
    char url[255];
    _snprintf(url, sizeof(url), "http://%s/remauth.php", "SITEADDRESS.com");

    char buf[8192] = {0};
    char postBuf[8192];
    _snprintf(postBuf, sizeof(postBuf), "%s&&%s", username, password);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, AuthDataReceived);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*)&buf);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "IW4M");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postBuf);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, -1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    CURLcode code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    curl_global_cleanup();

    if (code == CURLE_OK)
    {
        return Auth_ParseResultBuffer(buf);

    }
    else
    {
        Auth_Error(va("Could not reach the SITEADDRESS.comt server. Error code from   CURL: %x.", code));

    }

    return false;
  }

curl_global_cleanup();
return false;
}
```

and my remauth.php:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host=""; // Host name 
$dbusername=""; // Mysql username 
$dbpassword=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$dbusername", "$dbpassword") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die(mysql_error());

// Define $username and $password 
//$username=$username; 
//$password=md5($_POST['password']);
//$password=$password;

$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];
//$post_item[]='action='.$_POST['submit'];


// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if (md5(md5($row['salt']).md5($password)) == $row['password']){
    session_register("username");
    session_register("password"); 
    echo "#";
    return true;
 }
 else {
    echo "o";
    return false;
 }
}
else{
echo "o";
return false;
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

///////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting a curl error? Is the php script executed at all?

Have you added the SITEADDRESS merely for posting or is this a define which the compiler should replace with the website you want to connect to? If the second, this will not work inside "", as it is then treated as a literal and not replaced.

Also, you are calling curl_global_cleanup() twice, once inside the if clause and once at the end of the function. You should only call it once. Is your function possibly called multiple times? Then you should move the global init and cleanup elsewhere, as curl assumes them to only be called once in a program. This will not solve your actual problem, but it is good practice.

Comment: Thanks for reply you can see my complet cod here:  http://pastebin.com/4phspxKc  its can be helpful what i say! i have a very basic in php so i cant find(write) corrected php cod for this C++ cod and i need someone do that for me (if possible) the Method for php cod is same ( i think) :D

Comment: please invest some effort into narrowing down the problem. Check whether your error is in the c++ code _or_ the php code. Tell us what errors you have encountered.

Comment: The C++ cod is fine and i can compile it with no error and its work perfect becuas i tested : when i change the returned false value ((#) when user name and pass wrong)) with true value ((o) when use pass is true)) The app lunched Successfully its shown the user and pass not receive correctly with php cod and then the result off php com false(#)....

Comment: ---  and i add this the Application run with returned true value (o) from php result.

Comment: I think i have wrong in this section $username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];

Comment: I think curl needs to be told the name of the field which it shall post to. something like this: _snprintf(postBuf, sizeof(postBuf), "username=%s&password=%s", username, password); . You could do a print_r($_POST) in the php script to see what is posted to your webpage.

Comment: Thanks its worked :D   did possible to change somethings in php (i want the c++ file not changed)

Comment: Hi again : i found a site: www.brothersofnod.ru/remauth.php that used this method and when i open this page i get this error : **bold** `fail#You cannot login without a password.#1#Anonymous#anonymous@example.com#0# ` i think this method is correct so can someone what code in this php page?

Answer (score 0):

```
//To get the posted data without the fieldnames use: 

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

//And then split the data by '&&'

$new_data = explode('&&', $data);

$username = $new_data[0];

$password = $new_data[1];

// more code...
```